# Get Storage information from Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox-api

I used /reports/get_storage Business endpoint in the past and I now see it is depreciated, so what is the replacement? How can I get storage information?

Comment: You probably will get an answer much quicker on the Dropbox Community forum.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an exact replacement for that deprecated endpoint unfortunately, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

For a users current usage, refer to [/2/users/get_space_usage](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#users-get_space_usage). Or to calculate the usage in any particular path or namespace, sum the sizes from [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue]](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue).

See also [the "Member file access" documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#teams-member-file-access) for information on calling for a specific member from a team-linked app.